# Git clone doesn´t work, remote-https is not a git command?

Tags: git

I'm try to clone a repo from github, but git show this message:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter.git
Cloning into 'react-native-firebase-starter'...
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I've reinstall a many times git, but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide more information about your environment.  This error is due calling the incorrect executable.  Instead of submitting a comment, provide the relevant information as an edit, necessary to answer your question.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366101/git-remote-https-is-not-a-git-command

Comment: Please do provide the necessary information required to answer your question, instead of just confirming the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366101/git-remote-https-is-not-a-git-command) was helpful.

Comment: Git version that I'm running is 2.20.1 on windows 10
And that link isn't helpful for me

Comment: My problem is the path of environment variable, the path that works is **C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core**, thank you

Comment: Could easily be this, encountered this a long time ago too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474447/git-fatal-i-dont-handle-protocol-http

Comment: Also try removing the .git extension on your url

Comment: @SetJafet - Please edit your question, so your question contains all relevant information, instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm try to clone a repo from GitHub, but git show this message:
>
> `git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

You need to run the correct executable, based on your own feedback, you should be calling `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core` in order to accomplish your goal.